# where is cookie acceptance test in websphere 7 admin console?

Tags: websphere-7

I am getting the following errors in SystemOut logs:

> [11/4/11 2:53:13:876 ZZZ] 00000245 srt           W
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setStatus WARNING:
>   Cannot set status. Response already committed.
>
> [11/4/11 2:53:13:876 ZZZ] 00000245 srt           W
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse addHeader WARNING:
>   Cannot set header. Response already committed.

A bit of searching got me here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21316420

The solution talked about here says that we should disable "Cookie Acceptance test". But i am not able to find out where exactly is that checkbox in admin console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technote you are referring to is for a specific application (WebSphere Commerce). If you are getting these warnings with your own application, then the technote doesn't apply. What these warnings mean is that you have a JSP or servlet that calls setStatus or addHeader after too much output has already been written to the response. You need to determine where this happens and either fix your code or increase the output buffer size.